# Android: How to find the position clicked from the context menu

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a list view filled with data. I set up a context menu for the `listview` using the following code:

```
list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener
(
  new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() 
  {
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
        {
       AdapterContextMenuInfo mi =(AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
       menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete item");                
    }
   }
);
```

I have the following method override to control de contextmenu menuitem selected:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
  switch(item.getItemId()) 
  { 
  case 0: 
    ShowAlert("hello from delete item");
    break; 
  default: 
  return super.onContextItemSelected(item); 
  } 
  return true; 
}
```

In this overridden method, how could I find the item of the list view that was clicked?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo`.

Something like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
}
```

You can also get the exact `View` for which the menu is being displayed:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    View view = info.targetView;
}
```

Comment: info is always null in my case.. can anyone help ? I'm using gridview.

Comment: I've got it working finally, I was using custom GridView in which `getContextMenuInfo()` method was not implemented. I've posted [here](http://vinaybhargav.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/android-floating-context-menu-for-listviewgridview/) in case if someone need a sample.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final int EDIT_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
 @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT_ID, Menu.NONE, "Edit").setAlphabeticShortcut(
                'e');
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Delete")
                .setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT_ID:

            edit(info.id);
            return (true);
        case DELETE_ID:

            delete(info.id);
            return (true);
        }

        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
```

Comment: i tried this with recyclerview but it seems not to be working. any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

OK, to solve problem info null ****
use static member and  set value from Position of your holder 
to save the value in longclick method member for example:-

```
public class CurrentPosition {
   public static  int Pos{ get; set; }
}

public bool OnLongClick(View v)
{
    CurrentPosition.Pos = Position;
    return false;
}
```

and use in  your context select item:

```
public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case 0:
            return true;
        case 1:
            Toast.MakeText(this,CurrentPosition.Pos.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return true;
        case 2:
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Save", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

C# code